# Wahoo Kickr cassette compatibility with Campagnolo

Tags: shimano, compatibility, campagnolo, indoor, wahoo

I've recently got a really good deal on a Wahoo Kickr V4. I'm trying to make sure that I can use it with my current bike. I currently have 10 speed Campagnolo Veloce, so have heard that I may need the Campagnolo freehub for the Kickr.

If I buy a 10-speed Shimano cassette with the same sprocket sizes as my Campagnolo would it work well?
If not, can I use any Campagnolo freehub, or will only the Wahoo branded one work?

Also if I am using the Wahoo Campagnolo freehub, it mentions that it is only [compatible with cassettes with 4 inner arms](https://uk.wahoofitness.com/devices/indoor-cycling/parts-components/campagnolo-freehub-buy). How do I know if the cassette I am buying will have 4 or 8?

I am currently looking at the [Miche Primato 10X Campag 12/25](https://www.singletrackbikes.co.uk/m7b162s401p9780/Miche_Primato_10X_Cassette_/Cassettes/RS_GB)
And if the Shimano solution would work anyway I'll get the Shimano version.

Since I will be getting a new bike in a few months, I'm not too worried about creating the optimal solution, just one which will work, and won't damage my drivetrain components.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An S10 cassette will not shift well with a C10 drivetrain, and it would be unacceptable as a permanent solution if it were my bike. That said, the OP stated an intent to get a different bike. It's likely they can tune it to work well enough in a few gears. Reasoning is as follows.

I am not 100% sure if all the info on [this site](http://obike.dk/teknisk_info) is correct, but the parameters for Campy 10 and Shimano 10 road seem in line with what I remember. Consider the cog-cog spacing (distance between centerline of each cog) and the total cassette height. You will see that that a Shimano 10 cassette is shorter than a Campy 10. You will also see that the cog-cog spacing on C10 is 0.2mm more than for S10 - and moreover, the reported number is the *average* cog-cog distance on a C10 cassette, since they made the distance vary slightly at the ends of the cassette. They said it was to improve shift quality. Or perhaps they just wanted to be different.

For a permanent solution if you keep that C10 drivetrain, there are options.

1. If you are only going to do structured training, you can pick one cog that's quiet enough and leave the drivetrain in that cog, and use erg mode. This is perfectly acceptable as a practice. It does benefit athletes to do some intervals without erg on (i.e. sim mode) so they know what an effort level feels like. But you aren't going to lose a race on account of this.
2. Wahoo should soon release firmware for the Kickr series that allows Zwift's one-cog system to work. It [has already implemented](https://www.dcrainmaker.com/2024/02/wahoo-kickr-core-zwift-one-review-cog-click.html) that functionality for the Kickr Core. This is where the trainer has a single cog at the back, and a virtual shifter switch on your handlebar that tells the trainer to vary its internal resistance, simulating shifting. Wahoo should also release retrofit kits for all Kickrs soon (see towards the end of the article, search for *retrofit*). NOTE: previously the answer implied that the other Kickrs had updated firmware. I was wrong on this, but I expect the update soon.
3. Alternatively, you could put a cheap Shimano cassette on the rear, then shift to the 14t cog, and use the Zwift shifter. See [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0DjOtsFbvW4&t=258s) by Shane Miller. I believe you would need [this controller from Zwift](https://us.zwift.com/collections/all/products/zwift-play?variant=43737779896576), which is US$100 right now.
4. Or you could buy the [Zwift Cog upgrade kit](https://us.zwift.com/collections/all/products/zwift-cog-click-upgrade-kit?variant=43845806260480). The kit is a JetBlack freehub body (this company made the Zwift Hub trainer), one 14t cog, and two large black plastic spacers. Put the cog and spacers on the Kickr Core's freehub. Put the freehub body in the drawer. That's it. If you're in a cycling club, you could ask the riders who typically help people fix flats if they have the tools (a standard Shimano lockring tool and a chainwhip). You could acquire these tools yourself for future use. Unless you are totally devoted to Campy, you may get a Shimano bike at some point.
5. If you're upgrading to C11 or 12, you could just get a Shimano cassette for the trainer (or even your permanent wheelset). It will run fine. It will be a bit quieter and shift a bit smoother with a Shimano chain.

You cannot simply put any Campy freehub on the trainer. They won't fit. If you knew which original equipment manufacturer made the hub for the trainer, you *might* be able to take any of their freehubs and transplant them. Problem is we don't know who it is, and we don't even know the full set of possible manufacturers. Wahoo's trainers may have been made by [Magene](https://www.magene.com) at one point, but it's unlikely Wahoo will tell you - although it is possible Magene will tell you if they did and they might have spare freehubs - except that they are based in China and may not sell direct to the US.

The bit about 4 or 8 inner arms refers to this.

[image]

Campy freehubs have 8 splines. Now, if you take your cassette off, in a lot of cases, you should only see 4 splines cut into the big cogs. My Record 12 cassette has only 4 splines. Now, the problem is that I can't remember how many splines the 10s cassettes had. I think that Centaur and up had 4, but I can't remember if the Veloce cassettes (which are all loose cogs) had 8. Customer service at Miche might be able to help, but they're a smaller Italian company in Italy, and there might be language barriers. You might ask the retailer as well.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with the above comment. Shimano cassette (Which I have) just does not make the ride pleasant. The chain keeps jumping and skipping when changing gears.

I looking to change both to the same and then test it out.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. Stack Exchange sites do not work like a traditional forum. if you agree with the above statement (it is referred to as an answer on SE) then SE protocol would as that you upvote the answer you agree with. And if you desire, you could add a comment to the answer you agreed with.  Your comment here belongs there, not as a new answer. If you have an additional answer you the original question (Wahoo Kicker Campagnolo compatibility), then it is welcome as an answer.

Comment: Welcome - the way I read OP's question, they want to use a shimano cassette in the trainer permanently, and do normal riding with the rear wheel+campy cassette in the bike.  If that's what you do, the indexing could be off between the wheel cassette and trainer cassette.  You could shim the trainer's cassette to move it left/right to match the wheel.   Regardless, your reply is a "work in progress" and doesn't actualyl answer question as it stands.  When you've tried swapping, then please come back and use [edit] to add your experiences and results, which will make this into an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, as I read things, if you can clarify that you have a Shimano 10s cassette in a Campy 10s drivetrain, that may suffice. Your answer would then be a personal attestation that the mix doesn't work well, whereas the other answer is arguing based on theory.